# Add css style to php echo

Tags: styles, echo

I am trying to add css style to this echo.

```
// Execute the query
        if($stmt->execute()){
         echo "Record was updated.";
```

I have tried

```
 // Execute the query
        if($stmt->execute()){
         echo "<p style=\"font-color: red;\">Record was updated</p>";
```

and although there was no errors, the styling was not applied. How might I succeed in this please.

Comment: It's color not font-color. Voting to close as typo. Also, free ProTip™: prefer CSS classes instead of inline styles.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
echo '<p style="color: red;">Record was updated</p>';
```

instead of

```
echo "<p style=\"font-color: red;\">Record was updated</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($stmt->execute()){
 echo "<p style="color: red;">Record was updated</p>";
```

As for me i think that The main problem occur because in css if your want to change the color of text/font then we use `color:some color;` and you `font-color:some color;` which is wrong, and the other thing is you use \ in your code and I never seen the \ use with css in php, hope this description is enough for you to understand the issue...

If the answer solved your problem the Mark/consider it as your answer, if the answer is helpful for you then vote it as helpful...

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem, but it'd be great if you could add some more explanation of how/why this makes it work.  Don't forget there are heaps of rank newbies on S/O, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise... what may be obvious to you may not be so to them.

Comment: I went with 

`if($stmt->execute()){
         echo '<div class="alert">Record was updated</div>';

.alert {color: red;}`

Answer (score -1):

You Can also do it like this

```
if($stmt->execute())
{
echo '<font color=red>Record was updated</font>';
}
```

Comment: No. That's even more terrible than inline styles. The `<font>` element is also deprecated in HTML5.